# What is relation between preadditive category (as a ring) and semigroupoid (as a near-ring)?

Tags: category-theory

I am interested in finding a link between the preadditive categories when we talk about generalization of the rings with the semigroupoid when we talk about of generalization of near-rings. 
Is there a structure or a category that explains the difference that binds and join in a more abstract set, from the categorical point of view, the rings as preadditive categories with near-rings as semigroupoids?

=> A preadditive category is a category enriched over the category Ab of Abelian groups, where composition of morphisms is bilinear. A **ring** is then a preadditive category with a unique object.

Thus, a **near-ring** is a semigroupoid (rather than a category) of one unique object enriched over the category $Grp$ of groups, where composition of morphisms is linear. That is, $(f+g)∘h=f∘h+g∘h$ (if right-linear). The generalization just removes the “unique object” restriction.

I don’t know if this has a name in the literature, but I guess we could call such a structure a “colax Grp-semigroupoid”.

PS: I don't understand well but what is also difference between [near-ring modules](http://wiredspace.wits.ac.za/bitstream/handle/10539/20656/Berger%20Amelie%20Julie._Near-rings%20And%20Their%20Modules.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) and [quasi-modules](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/184362/6/06_chapter%201.pdf) ?